# How to change URL's to friendly URL in PHP (Htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to change:

```
example.com/movie.php?id=550
```

to

```
example.com/movie/550
```

This is my code in .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/error404.php

php_flag display_errors 1

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ movie.php?id=$1
```

This is what the code does:

It opens the page example.com/movie.php?id=550

When I type:

```
example.com/550
```

And When I type:

```
example.com/movie/550
```

then it redirects me to this URL:

```
example.com/movie.php?id=550
```

**Expected Result:**

When I type: `example.com/movie/550` it should open the content inside this page: `example.com/movie.php?id=550` (no redirect)

And when I type `example.com/550`, it re-directs me to example.com/error404.php page

Comment: I don't generally try to promote PHP frameworks when I don't know the skill level of a person, but combined with a very simply .htaccess, many of the PHP frameworks offer very powerful routing. Something like this would be very basic to achieve, and you can set rules that affect the entire site. This is just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some other redirection rule intervening here. The rule above certainly will internally rewrite as in the first example, it is not responsible for a redirection as you describe in the second example. Probably some other, general rewriting rule implemented by the framework you use.

About the specific rule, I assume that is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?movie/(\d+)/?$ /movie.php?id=$1
```

For that to work you obviously need the rewriting module to be active and you need to have the interpretation of dynamic configuration files enabled *if* you want to place the rule in one of those (see the `AllowOverride` directive). That would have to be located in your http hosts document root then.

Above rule will work in both, the http servers host configuration and likewise in dynamic configuration files.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I am not using any framework. I coded my whole website.

Comment: @Toby As written: your rewriting rule will _not_ result in such a redirection by itself.

Comment: Hey, How about I make a folder named "movie" and place movie.php inside it? What will be the code then? URL will be: example.com/movie/movie.php?id=550

Comment: Certainly possible, but _why_? Sounds strange and confusing to me. I don't see what the current issue is, why above rule does not do what you ask.

Comment: My Original Code shows the content of this page `example.com/movie.php?id=50` when I go to `example.com/500`. 

So I want it to show the content of `example.com/movie.php?id=550`, when I go to `example.com/movie/550`...So putting the file inside a folder named `movie`...might help me to achive what I want

Comment: I just need to make some changes to the code, but I tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to help. Need your help buddy, please :) thanks

Comment: No, creating such a folder will _not_ achieve what you are looking for. Above rewriting rules _should_ do that. So the question is, and I ask it once more since you did not answer: what is wrong with above rule? What is it that does _not_ work as expected for you when using the rule I posted?

Comment: It re-directs me to the original page, i.e `example.com/movie.php?id=50` 

I am not using any framework or anything like that...I have no idea, why it re-directs.

Comment: A request to `/movie/550` will _not_ get redirected by above rule, it will get rewritten internally. If there _really_ are no additional rules (did you check? how?) then probably you are looking at cached results. Clear your browsers cache or use an anonymous browser window for a test. Also examining the exact details of the server response in your browsers console would help. But do not try to find strange workarounds. Fix the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: @Toby Happens to all of us, don't worry! Have fun! ;-)